# Algorithm for independent set of a graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

is there an algorithm for finding all the independent sets of an directed graph ?
From what i've read an independent set represents a set formed by the nodes that are not adjacent. [image]

So for this example I would have {1} {2} {1,3}
So how is possible to find all of them, I am thinking about something recursive but I don't really know the algorithm, if someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated !

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical way to find independent sets is to consider the complement of a graph. A complement of a graph is defined as a graph with the same set of vertices and an edge between a pair if and only if there is no edge between them in the original graph. An independent set in the graph corresponds to a clique in the complements. Finding all the cliques is exponential in complexity so you can not improve brute force much. Still I believe considering the complement of the graph may make the problem easier to deal with.

Comment: Good idea, but the problem is I want ALL the sets and I can not find an algorithm for all the cliques, only for the maximal ones, any other ideas ?

Comment: The idea is the same you simply don't optimize. As I mentioned in my answer the solution to this problem is exponential so almost any solution should be approximately as good as you can do.

Comment: If you find all the maximal cliques, you have found all the cliques.

Comment: You can also try to find all the cycles and then check if it's also a clique. It's probably going to be exponential anyway (looks unavoidable)

Answer (score 2):

Other than complement and finding cliques, I can also think about "Graph Coloring", you color the vertices somehow that no two adjacent vertices have the same color (you can do it with a very simple heuristic algorithm like SL = Smallest Last), and then choose vertices in every color as a subset (as a maximal independent subset).

The only problem is that there are probably too many ways of coloring a graph. You have to keep all the found (maximal) independent sets and move on until you get enough sets!

Answer (score 2):

The Bron–Kerbosch algorithm is commonly used for this problem, see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron-Kerbosch_algorithm) for a description and pseudocode that can be turned into a useable program without too much problem. The size of output is, in the worst case, exponential in the number of vertices, but brute force will always be exponential while BK will be polynomial if the output is polynomial. In other words if you know that the output will be reasonable then BK will produce it in a reasonable time. This is an active area of research and there are a number of other algorithms that do the same thing with varying efficiency depending of the type and size of graph. There are applications in several areas, in particular genetics.

Comment: Hmm, the Wiki said "The Bron–Kerbosch algorithm is not an output-sensitive algorithm", so where did you get your claim that "BK will be polynomial if the output is polynomial"?

Comment: You're right, BK is not, in the worst case, output sensitive and there are other algorithms which are. BK does perform well in practice though, especially if you implement the optimizations discussed in the article, and it's relatively easy to implement.